# Copying .txt file content to .php file in a specific place

Tags: php

I cannot solve this for few hours already.

In my webserver vm in var/www/html folder i have:
1) db_ip.txt file with IP in it (10.10.10.10) 
2) connection.php file:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db_name");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

How can I replace the localhost with the ip, located in db_ip.txt file in ansible playbook?

Comment: would be esier to set php varaibles, `db_ip.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can use file_get_contents function to solve this.

```html
<?php
$source = file_get_contents("db_ip.txt");
$link = mysqli_connect($source, "root", "root", "db_name");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .ini instead of text like :

```
[db]
host = 1.1.1.1
```

In your code so the following: 
// Parse with sections

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true);
print_r($ini_arrat["db"]["host"]);
```